# c# и debug режим

Tags: c#, c++, clr

Можно ли в с# CLR код, запустить в "трассировочном" режиме? Можно ли  как-то перехватить вызов Invoke? Как можно написать дебаггер под с# код? Единственное что пока-что приходит в голову - емулировать выполнение CLR-кода, но тут нужно тонна кода на емулятор, а потом... перехватывать код готовых библиотек, ведь есть мостики CLR-Native-CLR, поэтому с емулятором не всё так просто. На `с++-cli` это чудо думаю было бы реально реализовать... но... Я думаю есть какой-то особый режим, который легко включается. Видел уже есть "кривые" аналоги VS... Как эта проблема решена в других проэктах?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, при попытке вбить в посиковик "debug" сразу выдает как ставить DebugPoint как отлаживать программу и кучу другого мусора.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как написать дебагер, а точнее трейсер.

1. С чего начать
2. Создание ICorDebug и ICorProcess
3. Создание обработчика
4. Апгрейт обработчика

Статья предполагает что базовые знания с++ есть. Дебагер можно писать на с++, можно даже на с#, но я предпочитаю с++. Покажу базу - как написать трейсер.

1. С чего начать. Давайте создадим простенький с#

   ```
   using System;
   public class Demo {
      public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
   }
   ```

   И соберём его `c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /platform:x86 /target:1.exe 1.cs /pdb:1.pdb /debug`

У студии есть папка SDK в которой можно найти нужные хедеры. У меня тут `SDK\v2.0\include`. Понадобятся следующие библиотеки

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include "COR\CorHdr.h"
    #include "COR\cor.h"
    #include "COR\cordebug.h"

    ICorDebug* dbg; // Библиотека дебаггера
    ICorProcess* process;//Процесс для отладки. Будет для одного процесса
```

Поначалу я думал - создам CoCreateIntance, там есть ф-ция CreateProcess - и будет всё ок, но нет.

2. Создание ICorDebug и ICorProcess. Второй создаётся легко, если создался первый. Есть несколько способов его создать, покажу один из. Если mscoree.dll не получается прилинковать - подключайте ёё через LoadLibrary и GetProcAddress. Есть две ф-ции, одна проверяет версию, другая - создает ICorDebug.

   ```
   void main(){
     wchar_t* module = "c:\\yourdebug\\1.exe";
     wchar_t ver[20];
     GetRequestedRuntimeVersion(module,ver,sizeof(ver),&dw);//mscoree.dll
     hr=CreateDebugginInterfaceFromVersion(CorDebugVersion_2_0,ver,&dbg);
     // hr=CreateDebugginInterfaceFromVersion(CorDebugVersion_2_0+1,ver,&dbg); // для .NET 4
     // Если не подходит версия - пробуйте менять первый аргумент
     //TODO: проверка hr
     hr = dbg->Initialize();
     STARTUPINFOW si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOW),0,};
     PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0,};
     // dbg->SetUnmanagedHandler           
     dbg->SetManagedHandler(MgrHandler); // ниже будет
     // TODO: параметры запуска можно будет доделать
     hr =  dbg->CreateProcess(module,module,0,0,true,
       CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, L"\0\0\0\0", L".", &si, &pi,0,&process);
     // TODO: цикл ожидания конца работы дебагера
     for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
       WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,1000);
     }
   ```

   Ну... почти готово. Или почти не считается. Долго мучался с SetManagedHandler, если ф-ция не работает, значит не все хандлеры вы описали. Теперь перейдем к...
3. Создание обработчика. В версии FrameWork 2.0 оказывается нужно поддерживать два каллбека. Ну и... коечего повписывать в обработчик. Нужно везде где можно написать `pAppDomain->Continue();` вписать его в каждый обработчик. Весь код приводить не буду, приведу главное. Дальше речь идет только об этом обработчике

   ```
   class MGRHandler:public ICorDebugManagedCallback,ICorDebugManagedCallback2{
      // 1 Рассказать какие у нас калбеки
      HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid,void**ppvObject){
         if (riid==IID_ICorDebugManagedCallback){
                *ppvObject=(ICorDebugManagedCallback*)this;//Первый
                 return 0;
                 }
         if (riid==IID_ICorDebugManagedCallback2){
                 *ppvObject=(ICorDebugManagedCallback2*)this;//Второй
                 return 0;
                 }
         return (HRESULT)-1;
         }
      // 2 Вначале нас бросит сюда
      HRESULT __stdcall CreateProcess(ICorDebugProcess* pProcess){
        pProcess->Continue(0);
        }
      // 3 Потом будет создан "домен"
      HRESULT __stdcall CreateAppDomain(ICorDebugProcess *pProcess,
      ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain) {
          pAppDomain->Attach(); // Переводим домен в дебаг режим
          pProcess->Continue(0);
          return 0;};
      // 4 Ставим Continue тут обязательно, желательно везде
      HRESULT __stdcall LoadAssembly(ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain,
       ICorDebugAssembly *pAssembly)  {           
       pAppDomain->Continue(0);return 0;
       }
      HRESULT __stdcall CreateThread(ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain,
       ICorDebugThread *thread) {          
          pAppDomain->Continue(0);return 0;
          };
   ```

   Аналогично ф-ции `Breakpoint`,`NameChange` и другие. 
   Перехват функций нужно делать в модуле, например так:

   ```
   HRESULT __stdcall LoadModule(ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain,
   ICorDebugModule *pModule) {
       ICorDebugFunction* fn=0;//ф-ция номер 1 имеет такой код 6000001
       pModule->GetFunctionFromToken(0x6000001,&fn);
       if (fn!=0) fn->CreateBreakpoint(&bp1);
       // TODO: очистить bp1  
       pAppDomain->Continue(0);          
       return 0;
       }
   ```

   И добавим обработчик BreakPoint

   ```
    HRESULT __stdcall Breakpoint(ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain,
    ICorDebugThread *pThread,
    ICorDebugBreakpoint *pBreakpoint) {            
        ICorDebugFrame * f = 0;
        pThread->GetActiveFrame(&f);
        ICorDebugStepper * step = 0;
        f->CreateStepper(&step);
        step->Step(0); // Заставляем работать в шаговом режиме
        // TODO: step освободить когда не нужен будет
        f->Release();
        pAppDomain->Continue(0);  
        return 0;
        }
   ```

   Да, добавьте `MGRHandler  MgrHandler;` под обработчиком, когда обработчик доконца допишите. Если компилятор ругается пишет слова `abstract` и `error` значит не все функции реализованы. Нужно все добавить (современные компиляторы умеют реализовать абстрактные классы сами, если дополнительно сделать два три клика в нужных местах).

Теперь дебагер может кое-как отлаживать программу. Столкнулся с тем... Ой, а где же мой ip....

4. Апгрейт обработчика. Есть интерфейс `ICorDebugILFrame` - в нем куча полезностей, локальные переменные, аргументы, и ip. Последний "штрих" программы, правим в обработчике ф-цию:

   ```
   HRESULT __stdcall StepComplete(
        ICorDebugAppDomain *pAppDomain,
        ICorDebugThread *pThread,
        ICorDebugStepper *pStepper,
        CorDebugStepReason reason) {
            ICorDebugFrame * f = 0;
            ICorDebugILFrame * ff = 0;
            unsigned ip,tok;
            pThread->GetActiveFrame(&f);
            f->QueryInterface(IID_ICorDebugILFrame , &ff);
            ff->GetIP(&ip);
            f->GetFunctionToken(&tok);
            char buf[30];
            wsprintfA("tok:%x ip:%x\r\n",tok,buf);
            // TODO: вывод на екран
            pStepper->Step(0); // пусть ещё шагает
            pAppDomain->Continue(0);
            return 0;
            }
   ```

Теперь получился "трейсер", который позволяет по-шагам выполнить ф-цию. Я не упомянул `IMetaDataImport` - через него можно получить имена всех ф-ций и параметров, остальную нужную информацию найти относительно легко. Я постарался показать 4-ре шага, которые мне было не очень просто найти. Показан чисто "скелет".

P.S. Тесты.

Модуль собран в borland c++ x86.

win2003 x86 -  модуль работает (студия 2005)

win7 x64 - модуль работает, но нужно создать 32-битную сборку отлаживаемой программы, т.е. добавить в `csc.exe` параметр `/platform:x86` (иначе ловим ошибку `DebuggerError` [0x80131C30](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/7274.aspx) )

Полезные ссылки

- MS debug api http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/
- Создание ICorDebug http://lowleveldesign.org/2010/10/11/writing-a-net-debugger-part-1-starting-the-debugging-session/ [Часть 2](http://lowleveldesign.org/2010/10/22/writing-a-net-debugger-part-2-handling-events-and-creating-wrappers/) [Часть 3](http://lowleveldesign.org/2010/11/08/writing-a-net-debugger-part-3-symbol-and-source-files/) [Часть 4](http://lowleveldesign.org/2010/12/01/writing-a-net-debugger-part-4-breakpoints/)
- Коды ошибoк HRESULT http://github.com/mrfearless/UASM-with-RadASM/blob/master/UASM64/ErrorCodes.dat Файл с кодами ошибок есть `corerror.h` но... он не удобный.