# Как добавить инструкцию перед каждой строкой кода в методе, не меняя код?

Tags: c#

Хочу чтобы такой код

```
[Dotter]
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    int y = 3,  x= 2;         
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {            
        y += x;
    }            
    Console.WriteLine(y);            
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Работал, как такой

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(".");
    int y = 3, x = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(".");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(".");
        y += x;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(".");
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    Console.WriteLine(".");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(".");
}
```

Реально это сделать и как?

Comment: Аспектно-ориентированное программирование в помощь ) Fody, PostSharp и другие либы

Comment: Тут ещё вопрос в том, что считать строкой кода. `y = 3, x = 2` - это же два выражения, на самом деле.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, интересный момент получился, хотя я и не специально. Но мне, на самом деле, именно в этом случае всё равно.

Comment: Кроме АОП, наверняка это можно сделать с помощью roslyn analyzer: [1](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix)

Comment: Ага, фигурная скобка тоже в отдельной строке

Comment: Может вам нужен трейсер, и вы хотите познакомится с дебагом? Тогда почитайте вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927959/c-%d0%b8-debug-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc/930954#930954 Если шарп греет вас больше чем плюсы, то по ссылкам найдете примеры на шарпе.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вообщем-то да, сабж мне нужен для самописного профилировщика, ибо замаялся расставлять и стирать контрольные точки. У Вас интересные варианты, но что-то сложноватые, хотя..

Comment: Если не нужна отладка, то можно переработать текст, и самому програмно добавить в текст нужные строки, и пересобрать. Думаю это будет самым простым вариантом (нужно только правильно посчитать к-во открывающих - закрывающих кавычек).

Comment: @nick_n_a Но вот с кавычками-то должен же Roslyn помочь по идее.. а обратно как?

Comment: А зачем обратно? Копируете в отдельную папку, натравливаете на неё компилятор - и получаете нужную сборку. А текущий код лучше не менять.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну а почему бы и нет. Интересно а отладчик никак не обмануть при этом? Ну это я так, наглею уже

Comment: Хотя не, есть другой метод. aspx когда генерирует cs-ки он передаёт в неё debug-info где какой метод искать.

Comment: Отладчик не нужно обманывать, можно ставить директиву #line, а процедуру мониторига поставить флаги "не для отладки".

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/520834/

Answer (score 3):

Не меняя кода метода, т. е. в рантайме этого сделать нельзя. Ну по крайней мере, если не писать полноценный декомпилятор. Всё из-за того, что компилятор довольно много всего додумывает сам и даже если суметь каким-то образом выявить (не знаю, насколько это возможно) границы операторов (statement), чтобы перед каждым из них что-то вставить, то на простейшем `foreach` уже будет несоответствие - вместо

```
foreach (var x in a)
  Console.WriteLine(x);
```

ты увидишь вот такое:

```
IEnumerator<int> enumerator = a.GetEnumerator();
try
{
  while (enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    int x = enumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
  }
}
finally
{
  if (enumerator != null)
  {
    enumerator.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Легкого варианта нету.

1. Полноценный трейс делается через дебаггер, на дебаггер есть ограничение - сам себя делать дебаг - нельзя. Как написать трейсер на с++ [c# и debug режим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927959/c-%d0%b8-debug-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc/930954#930954) так же там найдете ссылки на с# примеры.
2. Лучший вариант - пропустить код через текстовую "мясорубку" - добавить нужную строку в нужных местах кода, и пересобрать утилитой msbuild. Директива [#line](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-line) поможет сохранить нумерацию строк.
3. Рефлексия, ручной мини-трейсер. Приведу пример мини-трейсера, который кое-как трассирует данный код. В mi - передать результат ф-ции где-то так `typeof(My).GetMethod("Main")` Main сделать public, или познакомится с рефлексией ближе.

   ```
   void Invoker(MethodInfo mi)
   {// TODO: Добавить проброс аргументов 
       MethodBody b = mi.GetMethodBody();
       MethodBase mb = null;
       byte[] il = b.GetILAsByteArray();
       object[] stack = new object[b.MaxStackSize];
       object[] locals = new object[b.LocalVariables.Count];
       int sp = 0; // Указатель стека
       int pc = 0; // Указатель кода
       int i = 0, tok = 0;
                   while (pc < il.Length){
       // Добавить Console.Write("."); например    
       switch (il[pc++]) // пли
           {
               // TODO: добавить обработку опкодов
               case 0: continue;
               case 6: stack[sp++] = locals[0]; continue;
               case 7: stack[sp++] = locals[1]; continue;
               case 8: stack[sp++] = locals[2]; continue;

               case 0x0A: locals[0] = stack[--sp]; continue; //stloc.0
               case 0x0B: locals[1] = stack[--sp]; continue;//stloc.1
               case 0x0C: locals[2] = stack[--sp]; continue;//stloc.2
               case 0x16: stack[sp++] = 0; continue;  // ldc.i4.0
               case 0x17: stack[sp++] = 1; continue;  // ldc.i4.1
               case 0x18: stack[sp++] = 2; continue;  // ldc.i4.2
               case 0x19: stack[sp++] = 3; continue;  // ldc.i4.3
               case 0x1F: stack[sp++] = (int)il[pc++]; continue;  // ldc.i4.n
               case 0x2B: pc += il[pc]+(il[pc] >= 0x80 ? -255 : 1); continue;
               case 0x2D: sp--; if ((stack[sp] is int) && ((int)stack[sp] > 0)) pc += il[pc++] + (il[pc] >= 0x80 ? -255 : 1); else pc++; continue; //
               case 0x2A: return; // ret
           case 0x32: sp -= 2; if ((int)stack[sp] < (int)stack[sp + 1]) pc += il[pc] + (il[pc]>=0x80 ? -255 : 1); else pc++; continue; // btl.s

               case 0x58: stack[sp - 2] = (int)stack[sp - 2] + (int)stack[sp - 1]; sp--; continue; // add грубо
               case 0x28: {         // static call
                       tok = BitConverter.ToInt32(il, pc); pc += 4;
                       mb = mi.Module.ResolveMethod(tok);
                       i = mb.GetParameters().Length;
                       object[] pars = new object[i];
                       while (i > 0) pars[--i] = stack[--sp];
                       stack[sp++] = mb.Invoke(null, pars);
                       if (mb.GetType().GetProperty("ReturnType").GetValue(mb,null) == typeof(void)) sp--;
                   }
                   continue;
               case 0x8C: pc += 4; continue; // box  грубо
               case 0xFE: pc++; 
                   if (il[pc - 1] == 4) { stack[sp - 2] = ((int)stack[sp - 2] > (int)stack[sp - 1]) ? 1 : 0; sp--; };//clt грубо не проверял
                   continue;
           }
      }
   }
   ```

Для трассировки любого кода прийдется 1)дописать (реализовать) кучу инструкций. 2)познакомится с всеми видами токенов. 3)реализовать инициализацию локальных переменных 4)реализовать обработку исключений. Возможно на гите похожего монстра к-то выложил - не могу сказать, или что-то похожее можно найти в открытом доступе.

Список инструкций есть тут http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions

И долгими (зимними) вечерами можно наслаждаться отладкой этой ф-ции наблюдая как алгоритм трассирует код процедуры main.